# How to redirect user to PWA using URL

Tags: html, polymer, progressive-web-apps

I want to redirect user to my PWA from a link in an email and/or other application. This doesn't work now because on iphone it redirects to the Safari browser instead of the PWA.

Anybody a solution/idea for this?